# Jordan form of T*

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the relation between the Jordan form of $T$ and $T^*$ in an unitary vector space?
If they have the same eigenvectors, we can prove that $T$ is normal.
So I wanted to do this with the Jordan form.

Comment: It's well known that $T$ and its transpose have the same Jordan forms.  $T^*$ is the conjugate of the transpose of $T$.

Comment: That is in an ortonormal basis.What happens in the basis of Jordan?

Comment: $$\overline{SAS^{-1}} = \overline{S}\,\overline{A}\,\overline{S}^{-1}$$